# How to run examples : No such module AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

Steps to reproduce:

- git clone AudioKit (master branch)
- In xCode, open an example project. e.g  `Examples/iOS/SequencerDemo/SequencerDemo.xcodeproj`
- build (try to run, with a Simulator target)

  - I get a: `No such module AudioKit` in `ViewController.Swift:9`

Analysis:

- In the SequencerDemo Target, under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` I DO see the `AudioKit.framework` and it has the correct path.

Details:

- I am using xCode 10.3 (on OSX Catalina, 10.15 Beta)
- master branch commit: 3e6945ad6820f6103e95ca18ec6607ee64e5bed3

P.S: I am a Swift/xCode noob, so I might be missing something trivial here.

Answer (score 2):

If you clone the repo, you still need to build the framework:

From the terminal in the directory you cloned AUdioKit:

cd Frameworks
   ./build_frameworks.sh

Check out the Frameworks [README](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Frameworks) for more information.